# How to IGNORE breakpoints and go to a line directly where cursor is in VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to understand VS Debugging Techniques.

Situation 1: 
I have a `100 line` of code. I have break point as `10,20,30,40`. Currently my debugger is at `line 20`. And Now I realize that I want to go to line 50 (Kindly note that I DO NOT HAVE any breakpoint there). So I click on `line 50`. So is there any way I can go to line 50. P.S: I `don't want to skip the execution` of previous lines. I want the debugger to execute till line 49 properly w/o stopping at any previous breakpoint and stop at line 50. Is it possible?

Situation 2:

I have a `100 line` of code. I have break point as `10,20,30,40`. Currently my debugger is at `line 20`. And Now I realize that I want to go to line 40 (Kindly note that I do HAVE A breakpoint there). So I click on `line 40`. Is there any way I can go to line 40. P.S: I `don't want to skip the execution` of previous lines. I want the debugger to execute till line 39 properly w/o stopping at any breakpoint and stop at line 40. Is it possible?

Please guide me if it's possible. And you could tell me keyboard shortcut too that will be awesome.

P.S: If any of the situation 1 or 2 is possible I can live with that as that will be huge help to me. If I can click on a line then I can always put a breakpoint (no laziness) provided I know that I can directly reach to that line ignoring all the previous breakpoints :)

Comment: It is a feature in VS2017.  When you hover the mouse over the line you get a little triangle-shaped glyph on the left of the line with the tooltip "Run execution until here".  Click it.  It will not ignore any intermediate breakpoints.  As good as it gets.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for your answer. I will try that. I am just little surprised that it was not there till 2017. Anyways Thanks!

Comment: The UI is different in previous versions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/05/run-to-cursor/

Comment: In previous versions, there is an option in the right-click menu while debugging - something like "run to" or "run to line". I do this often in VS 2015, and have done it in VS 2012 and 2013 too.